# Formatting date time application wide

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, format

I have an MVC app and I need to use datetime format for Turkey. I have datitime being used all over the place. Is there a way i can do this at one place and it will be formatted.

I remember reading something about Thread CurrentCulture long time ago?

How can i get this done? any ideas?

Comment: Is your OS regional settings set for Turkey?  Usually the default formatting/ToString for types (especially like DateTime) will be culture-aware.

Comment: no my OS is pacific time. California dude.

Comment: Do you JUST need the datetime and not numbers? You should be very careful about setting your culture to Turkey, because that will also effect the way that numbers are formatted (and parsed as well). Jeff Atwood has an entire blog post about Turkey! http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html. Do you need to just display things in that format or read them in that format as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the culture and UI culture via your web.config, using the globalization element of system.web

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162

You may also consider adding a partial for DateTime in your DisplayTemplates:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Vyktor thanks, looks like you're forced to specify a particular version in the links now, so I added (v=vs.100) to them and they seem to work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your web application culture settings in you web.config file. For example the following one will use settings based on user's web browser language preferences:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
</system.web>
```

Alternatively you can set the specific values. [List of cultures in .NET](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider something like below in your Global.asax:

```
using System.Globalization;

internal void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tk-TR");

}
```